# Java Abstract Class Method

Tags: java, abstract-class

I came across this code in an exercise for declaring an abstract class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Box {

    public abstract void add(Item item);

    public void add(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        for (Item item : items) {
            Box.this.add(item);
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean isInBox(Item item);
}
```

I am not able to understand what the `add(ArrayList<Item> item)` method does. I get it that it loops through an `ArrayList` called items but what does `Box.this.add(item)` do?
Can someone clarify this?

Comment: It's the same thing as `this.add(item)` or just `add(item)` in that case. The developer just decided to qualify the method call beyond the usual.

Comment: Basically: bad style. And note: the bad style continues, as it would be **much** better if that method `add(ArrayList<Item> items)` would be named `addAll(List<T> items)`. 1) to avoid mixing up add() and addAll() ... 2) to use the interface List instead of some implementation type ArrayList ... to make the Box class generic itself.

Comment: This whole `Box` could be an interface.

Answer (score 4):

On top of what @ernest_k wrote in a comment there is an actual use-case where you actually need to qualify a method call with the class name like this: If you create an anonymous inner class in a method that accesses fields of its outer class, like the following arbitrary (and quite useless in reality) example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Box {

    public abstract void add(String item);

    public void add(ArrayList<String> items) {
        for (String item : items) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    add(item); // works, implicitly accesses Box.this.add
                    this.add(item); // does not work as "add" is not a method of the anonymous runnable
                    Box.this.add(item); // works
                }
            };
            r.run();
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean isInBox(String item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That class is declaring an interface with some code already in. Specifically, it is declaring a **Box** without a detailed implementation, in which you can later create the **Box** with the underlying code that suits your needs.

For example, you can declare the **BoxOnSet** class, that implements that declaration with a *HashSet<>*:

```
public abstract class BoxOnSet extends Box {
    public BoxOnSet()
    {
        this.items = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void add(Item item)
    {
        this.items.add( item );
    }


    public boolean isInBox(Item item)
    {
        return this.items.contains( item );
    }

    private HashSet<Item> items;
}
```

As for your specific question, the `add(ArrayList<>)` method is equivalent to the collections *addAll()* method. It just uses the abstract `add(Item)` in order to insert items in the **Box**. You can specify `add( item )`, `this.add( item )` or even `Box.this.add( item )`, and in this example all point to the same method, they are just ways to specify further.

Comment: The  user mainly asks about the the quirky Box.this syntax ...

Comment: The abstract class declaration of Box does not contain any ArrayList. I was wondering to what the item would be added.

Comment: @Ramkay, the `ArrayList` is the parameter of the second `add()` method, which should've been named `addAll()` or similar to make it obvious that does something extended.. The **Box** class is abstract, so it is left to the derived classes what to add **Item**s to.